# Generate big ( ~300MB) LMDB file

Tags: go, lmdb

I am generating a huge LMDB file close to 300 MB and it takes hours in Golang. Is there a way to generate it within minutes? I am open to use any other language.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I have like 1.3 Million key-value to write

Comment: You need to post your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are committing the transaction after every single write, avoid it. Commit the transaction after completion of all writes.